# Quarkus testing using @QuarkusTest, mocks and javax.enterprise.inject.Instance

Tags: java, cdi, quarkus

We have an application that uses javax.enterprise.inject.Instance to find all validators for a service. This seems to work nicely but during testing we would like to swap out a few of those validators with a mock to skip their behaviour so it's easier to reach other validators.

When we try to do this using the 'Old approach' (See [Blog-post on this](https://quarkus.io/blog/mocking/)) we notice only the classes with @Mock are injected, not any of the normal ones.

When trying it the 'New approach' we get a javax.enterprise.inject.AmbiguousResolutionException that tells us TypeBValidator is found twice.

This is the setup of a trimmed-down version of our app showing the behaviour:

- Validator-interface
- TypeAValidator (`@ApplicationScoped`)
- TypeBValidator (`@ApplicationScoped`)
- REST-Service-class that has a @Inject like this: `Instance<Validator> validators` via the constructor.

In test-scope we have:

- TypeBMockValidator (which does have @Mock in old and **no** @Mock in the new approach)
- Test class for REST-Service that is annotated with `@QuarkusTest`. This test-class calls the REST-service using restassured, right as it's provided when one generates [an example project](https://code.quarkus.io/).

See [the example project](https://github.com/gkfirst8/quarkus-test-instance-example) for all details.

I'm looking for a stable and predictable way to replace only the TypeBValidator during my tests. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like something we should look into in Quarkus. Please open an issue on GitHub

Comment: Issue opened: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/19773

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this was not a bug, but the expected behavior of CDI when multiple there is a class hierarchy where multiple classes are beans.
In this case, the simplest solution is to annotate `TypeBValidator` with `@DefaultBean`.

See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/19773#issuecomment-909974623 for more details